# Does a system of (n-1) strictly concave equations and one linear equation have a unique solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have a system of $n$ equations and $n$ variables of the form

$$f_1(x_1,...,x_n) = y_1$$
  $$f_2(x_1,...,x_n) = y_2$$
  $$ ... $$
    $$f_{n-1}(x_1,...,x_n) = y_{n-1}$$
  $$x_1 + ... + x_n = y_n$$

where each $f_i$ is strictly concave. If the last equation was also strictly concave, I would know that if the system has a solution it must be unique.

However, the last equation is linear. I think the answer should be yes because I can always write a solution to this system (if it exists) as a solution to the program

$$\min_{x_1,...,x_n} (x_1 + ... + x_n - y_n)^2$$
  $$\text{ Subject to : } f_i(x_1,...,x_n) = y_i \text{ for all } 1 \leq i \leq n-1$$

which is a strictly convex minimization program subject to a concave constraint., but I'm worried I'm making a mistake by doing this transformation.

Comment: The answer seems to be obviously not because, for example, the system

$$x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1$$
$$x_1 = -x_2$$

has two solutions. But I'm still not sure why the ``solution" I gave above does not work.

Comment: What result are you referring to in "If the last equation was also strictly concave, I would know that if the system has a solution it must be unique."? You can adapt the counterexample in your last comment to use any $ax_1^2+bx_2^2=(a+b)/2$ instead of $x_1=-x_2$, for example $3x_1^2+x_2^2=2$.

Comment: This is in no way a "convex optimization" problem as tagged. Nonlinear equality constraints are not convex, even if the nonlinearity is convex or concave.

Comment: I changed the tags